# writing custom test profile, but get "does not map to any root"

Tags: quarkus

When I write a custom profile, it shows the config does not map to any root.

public class MyTestProfile implements QuarkusTestProfile {

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getConfigOverrides() {
    return Collections.singletonMap("self.debug","true");
}
```

}